# How to get checkbox value from ajax loaded content

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have external file which generate the checkbox list. And this file was load through jquery load. I want the checkbox click and update its parent div with something.

**html**

```
<div id="testiContent"></div>
```

**checkbox.php**

```
<div class="alert alert-info"><input type='checkbox' class='groupid' value='1'>1</div>
<div class="alert alert-info"><input type='checkbox' class='groupid' value='2'>2</div>
<div class="alert alert-info"><input type='checkbox' class='groupid' value='3'>3</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$('#testiContent').load('checkbox.php');//load file via ajax
$("#testiContent input.groupid").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $(this).parents().addClass("alert alert-success"); 
    }else{
        $(this).parent().removeClass("alert alert-success");  
    }
});
```

Ideally, when the checkbox click, then the alert div will change into green. I can make it working on the normal scrip but not a chance with ajax.

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/o6Lk17db/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind to an element that isn't there yet, so your dynamically added ones aren't subject to the `$"#testiContent input.groupid"` selector. The way around this is to bind to something that *is* already present. For example, the parent container where your elements are dynamically being added.

Try something like this:

```
$("#testiContent").on('change', 'input', function(){ ... });
```

will attach a listener to the parent, specifically for events on the appropriate (`input`) targets within that parent.

Answer (score 3):

My hunch is that you are simply attaching the `change` listener before the content is loaded in the DOM, so it doesn't actually target anything.  You *could* pass a callback function to load only attempt to attach the `change` listener after the content is in the DOM, but it might be easier to just use the `on` method on the document-- that way it is evergreen and doesn't need to rely on callbacks:

```
$('#testiContent').load('checkbox.php');//load file via ajax
$(document).on('change', 'input.groupid', function(e){
    var target = e.target;
    if($(target).is(":checked")){
        $(target).parents().addClass("alert alert-success"); 
    }else{
        $(target).parent().removeClass("alert alert-success");  
    }
});
```

That may not be exactly right but I think it will at least trigger.

Answer (score 1):

When html controls are loaded dynamically, events for these controls needs to be bind manually. So you need to bind check/click events once element adding is done. You can write code as

```
$(document).on("change","input.groupid").change(function(){
  // your code here
});
```

Comment: something coming up but : Cannot create property 'guid' on string '#testiContent input.groupid'

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$("input.groupid").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
  alert($("input.groupid").val());
    $(this).closest('div').removeClass("alert-info");
    $(this).closest('div').addClass("alert-success");
  } else {
    $(this).closest('div').removeClass("alert-success");
    $(this).closest('div').addClass("alert-info");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use change event on document because the content is loaded via ajax. and you can use toggleclass function for change the parent div.

```
$('#testiContent').load('checkbox.php');//load file via ajax
$(document).on('change', '.groupid', function(e) {
    $(this).closest("div").toggleClass("alert-success alert-info"); 
});
```